# Magento (Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "nnnnnn" already exist)

Tags: magento

While trying to change the status of an attribute from out of stock to pre order we caused the error below. This happend after using the data profiler to import a CSV containing SKU's with updated attribute data, we expected the import to update the the products for those SKU's but it seems to have created duplicate items.

When looking at one of the products in the admin the status had been changed to the correct value but the product was no longer displaying in the site, there was an error message for all the products updated.

We fixed this by adding a groupby clause in the view but obviously this is just a temporary fix to get the site working again. I need to find and remove the duplcate items but not being an expert with Magento and EVA I thought I'd ask if anyone had done this and what was the correct approach.

```
Error:
Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "nnnnnn" already exist

Trace:
#0
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collect
ion/Abstract.php(267):
Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#1
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collect
ion/Abstract.php(1057):
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addItem(Object(Mage_Catalog_Mod
el_Product))
#2
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collect
ion/Abstract.php(871):
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#3
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Observer.ph
p(78): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#4
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1303)
:
Mage_Review_Model_Observer->catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml(Obje
ct(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1278)
:
Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Review_Model_Observer
), 'catalogBlockPro...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/Mage.php(416):
Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
#7
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/L
ist.php(190): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
#8
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(
862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#9
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(
582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(
526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#11
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/
View.php(85): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#12
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/design/frontend/horticulture/default/te
mplate/catalog/category/view.phtml(295):
Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#13
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(
241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#14
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(
272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/hortic...')
#15
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(
286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#16
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(
863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php
(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(
863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#19
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(
582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(
526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#21
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/design/frontend/horticulture/default/te
mplate/page/3columns.phtml(59):
Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#22
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(
241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#23
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(
272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/hortic...')
#24
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(
286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(
863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(52
9): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/A
ction.php(392): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Cate
goryController.php(159):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/A
ction.php(421): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#30
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/
Router/Standard.php(250):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#31
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/F
ront.php(176):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Contro
ller_Request_Http))
#32
/var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/app/Mage.php(640):
Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /var/www/vhosts/magento/htdocs/index.php(84):
Mage::run('hedgenursery', 'website')
#35 {main}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628764/magento-reports-products-products-ordered-issue-item-mage-catalog-model-pr

Answer (score 1):

Find where the collection is being built. There you can check which table is the culprit. `LEFT JOINS` are suspicious.

You can check the query with

```php
$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Then find the duplicate item in your table and remove it. Don't fix this in code as this is a data error.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I have tried below solution its worked for me.

Solution:

Edit: /www/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php
Line: 256

Replace: `return parent::addItem($object);`

With: `try { return parent::addItem($object); } catch (Exception $ex) { }`

Comment: This is not a good solution, first of all you should not be editing core files, secondly you're not actually fixing the issue, you're just silencing the error